# Use Firebase Auth data and users for multiple projects and apps

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

If I have multiple apps with Firebase (different types and kinds) but want to be able to have 1 user base for all of them (1 account for all apps, even if they only use 1) how would I do this? I was thinking either 1. cloud function (every time someone signs up, add them as a user in the other apps) or 2. A separate project for Auth only and configure both of them in the app, but that might mean requests to firestore, storage, and functions aren’t authorized. NOTE: I'm willing to use GCP products separate from firebase to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the apps are all part of the same suite, you can add them to a single Firebase project. This is by far the easiest way to do this, but there is a hard limit on how many apps you can have in a project in this way (according to the [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#apps-per-project), this is 30 at the moment).

If the apps are not all part of the same suite, or you need more than the limit, your only option is to use custom authentication. This means you'll create a custom authentication provider that takes the user's credentials, verifies them, and then [creates a UID and token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for that user to the client which then [uses it to sign in to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).

In the back-end you could possible use a single Firebase project for then generating all these users, although I'll admit it's been a few years since I did that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll use option 2 to future proof. plus we do that sometimes as is already for clients that aren't mobile such as embedded smart home.